# Python3のstatsでピークが2個ある確率密度関数を作りたい

Tags: python, python3, numpy, scipy

statsでピークが2個ある確率密度関数を作成して次の処理を行いたいと考えています
・matplotlibによるグラフ作成
・stats.entropyによるKLダイバージェンスの算出

どのように実装すればよいでしょうか？

環境は下記のとおりです
Python 3.5.2
scipy  1.1.0
matplotlib  2.2.3                 
numpy  1.14.2

参考にしたWebサイト
Qiita 生成モデルで語られる Kullback-Leibler を理解する
https://qiita.com/TomokIshii/items/b9a11c19bd5c36ad0287

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 役に立つかどうか分かりませんが、[KL divergence over samples from distributions(aka entropy)](https://github.com/red-cheese/kl-divergence/blob/master/KLdiv.py) が参考になるかもしれません。

Comment: ソースコードの確認と、当方の環境で実行を行いました。私の希望する内容に非常に近いことができそうだと感じました。

Comment: @codeZ さん、スタック・オーバーフローでは、自己解決した場合[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)することができ、また推奨しています。もし自己解決しましたら、よろしければお願いいたします :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

metropolis さまにご教授頂いたコードを参考に、問題の解決ができました。
ポイントとして、numpyのconcatenateを用いて配列を連結してからPDFを作成するということでした。

https://github.com/red-cheese/kl-divergence/blob/master/KLdiv.py